# 'Almost people' or 'Almost all people'?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

My japanese students always insist on using 'almost people'. It doesn't sound correct to me but I can't seem to explain clearly. Please tell me if this phrase is really wrong or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, depends.  You could easily say "Oompah Loompahs are *almost people*" (but they're not, so it's ok for Willy Wonka to enslave them). But I don't imagine that's the kind of construction you're asking after. Can you give us an example sentence, please?

Comment: This must be due to the way ほとんど is used in Japanese. It certainly is wrong.

Comment: @DanBron example: Almost Japanese think English is difficult.

Comment: How is this off-topic?  It's clearly a question about English grammar and the answer will be similar to @Nothingatall's comment and/or an explanation that will be effective for the Japanese students.